# Is there anyway to define defaults for multidimensional attribute trees in Chef?

Tags: ruby, attributes, chef-recipe, chef-infra

### Typical use case of default attributes

Recipe attributes:

```
default['human']['jack']['arms'] = 2
default['human']['jack']['legs'] = 2
default['human']['jack']['heads'] = 1
```

In node/role:

```
override['human']['jack']['legs'] = 1
```

Also in recipe:

```
node.override['human']['jack']['legs'] = 1
```

### My use case with dynamic collections

*So what if my recipe doesn't know Jack will exist for a node/role and I want a dynamic collection for lots of entries. What is a good strategy to define or merge in defaults?*

I don't want to suggest a solution so I'll use a *made up wildcard* for my example where Jack and Jill are different but I don't have to define defaults (like two arms and a head) every time I define a new instance.

Recipe attributes:

```
default['human'][*] = { 
    "arms" => 2,
    "legs" => 2,
    "heads" => 1
}
```

In node/role:

```
default['human']['jack'] = { 
    "legs" => "1"
}
default['human']['jill'] = { 
    "superpower" => "flying"
}
```

Comment: BTW I chose examples because I couldn't easily describe the question. Here is a third party who solved how to "Provide Defaults for Multi-Element Attribute Trees" with a custom [merge_attribute_tree](http://omniti.com/seeds/seeds-our-experiences-with-chef-cookbook-and-attribute-design). Surely chef/ruby has a clean, built-in solution

Comment: You may be better off using data bags for this. Failing that, you might consider making a default hash that contains, for lack of a better phrase, templates that you can copy from in the recipe itself.

Comment: Yes we do make use of databags but I don't see how they help the logic to merge defaults in when not defined for the instance... How have you solved that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, chef attributes use deep merge and you can do this in the recipe, see http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_node_object_deep_merge.html

Do this in the recipe:

```
node['nginx']['sites'].each_key do |site|
  node.default['nginx']['sites'][site] = node['nginx']['site_defaults']
end
log JSON.pretty_generate(node['nginx']['sites'])
```

Cookbook attributes:

```
default['nginx']['site_defaults']['listen'] = [80]
default['nginx']['site_defaults']['location'] = '/'
default['nginx']['site_defaults']['index'] = ['index.html','index.htm']
default['nginx']['sites']['api']['index'] = 'api.cgi'
```

In node/role:

```
"nginx" : {
  "sites" : {
    "blog" : {
      "location" : "/blog/",
      "listen" : [443]
    },
    "wiki" : {
      "index" : ["index.php"] 
    }
  }
},
```

Produces

```
  * log[{
  "api": {
    "listen": [
      80
    ],
    "location": "/",
    "index": [
      "index.html",
      "index.htm"
    ]
  },
  "blog": {
    "listen": [
      443
    ],
    "location": "/blog/",
    "index": [
      "index.html",
      "index.htm"
    ]
  },
  "wiki": {
    "listen": [
      80
    ],
    "location": "/",
    "index": [
      "index.php"
    ]
  }
}] action write
```

Note that if you do this, the recipe default has higher precedence over the attributes default so the api index was overridden. The following would work.

```
force_default['nginx']['sites']['api']['index'] = 'api.cgi'
```

Also be very careful of Arrays, sometimes they are merged other times replaced (above).